# Condensing two instances of scanner class into one

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have created a method to translate multiple lines into Pig Latin. The expected input looks like so:

```
The cat jumped over the fox
```

My code outputs the text, correctly translated into Pig Latin and with the proper formatting (i.e. words separated out, lines separated out. However, I do this by using two instances of the scanner class.
Could anyone suggest how I could remove the two instances and condense them into one?

By the way, feel free to offer any other suggestions, but bear in mind I am a novice who is still learning!

```
    File file = new File("projectdata.txt");
    try 
    {
        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(file);
        while (scan1.hasNextLine()) 
        {
            Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(scan1.nextLine());
            while (scan2.hasNext())
            {
                String s = scan2.next();
                boolean moreThanOneSyllable = Syllable.hasMultipleSyllables(s);
                char firstLetter = s.charAt(0);
                String output = "";
                if (!moreThanOneSyllable && "aeiou".indexOf(firstLetter) >= 0)
                    output = s + "hay" + " ";
                else if (moreThanOneSyllable && "aeiou".indexOf(firstLetter) >= 0)
                    output = s + "way" + " ";
                else 
                {
                    String restOfWord = s.substring(1);
                    output = restOfWord + firstLetter + "ay" + " ";
                }
                System.out.print(output);
            }
            System.out.println("");
            scan2.close();
        }
        scan1.close();
    } 

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note: I had posted something similar on Code Overflow a few days ago and have taken some advice from the answer I was given there. However, whilst someone recommended not using two scanner classes, I just couldn't get the formatting right.

Comment: You can just remove the outer while loop, and `sc1` scanner object. They are useless here.

Comment: @RohitJain: But if I do that, it stops outputting the text on correct lines. Rather than the expected four/five words on each line, all words are output in a long stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your outer-loop you can read the file line-by-line. With the outer-loop you treat each line read as a string.

```
Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(scan1.nextLine());
```

With that you are trying to read a `String` using a `Scanner`. You should change it as follows:

```
String line = scan1.nextLine();
```

Split the line into an array of strings (words) and work on it.

```
String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
```

The inner loop can just iterate through the array.

```
for(String word : words) {
    //your existing logic can go here
}
```

**Update**

You can just escape the empty lines as follows. Any exception handling is not required.

```
String line = scan1.nextLine();
if(line.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println();
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Your answer looks perfect, but generates an error (I should have been more specific in my question). The poem is line after line, but is divided into four stanzas, meaning there are four lines that are empty. I am assuming I need to write a catch to account for these lines, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Just escape the line if it's empty. Use `if` to check it it's empty and `continue` to escape it.

Comment: The things you learn daily! Had no idea the Java had an isEmpty() method to check if a line was empty. I added one line to your final answer (a println statement in the isEmpty method), which ensures all stanzas are kept when printing out. Thanks for all your help!!